# services working fine on rest client but not on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am performing load testing of my web based application.

The service page is working fine on Advance Rest Client application but it is giving `404 page not found` error on Jmeter.

Please guide me how to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

404 means your url is probably wrong.

Show your configuration of Test plan for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request and response details, HTTP 404 response code usually stands for non-existent URL.

Most likely you'll also have to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send the relevant `Content-Type` header as your request might not be properly handled due to missing or incorrect content type.

I would recommend using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) to compare what's being send by the "Advance Rest Client" and by JMeter and tweak JMeter test accordingly. If you fail to figure that out by yourself - you can upload captured traffic files somewhere so we could take a look.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for baseline JMeter configuration for testing web services.